# Why cathode rays produce visible light on hitting glass but X-rays on hitting denser material?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, material-science, x-rays

Why cathode rays produce visible light on hitting glass but they produce x rays on hitting denser material ? I mean what is the difference in denser atoms that cause x rays rather than visible light .

Answer (score 1):

A typical CRT has phosphor coating the glass which emits light by luminescence when struck by electrons.  The accelerating potential in a CRT is about 20 kV as I recall.  X-ray tubes work mostly via Bremmsstrahlung radiation.  This requires higher energies; 50 kV or more.  The target needs to be dense since want to slow down the electrons; tungsten, molybdenum, copper, etc.  There is a sharp spectral cutoff in Bremmsstrahlung, $\lambda_{\hbox{min}}$, associated with the minimum kinetic energy of the electrons.  [See wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung)

Comment: The [original cathode ray tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_tube) glowed because the glass envelope itself was weakly phosphorescent.

Comment: Cool @jameslarge, excellent point.

Comment: ...due to heavy metal atoms present as impurities in the glass. modern vacuum tubes do this too.

Comment: Interesting @nielsnielsen.  I use vacuum tubes in the lab and I've never seen one glow green. I have used them to make x-rays though.

Comment: @johnscales, beam power pentodes (6AQ5, 6BQ5, 6V6, 6L6, 7027A, 6550, etc.)  glow a deep blue color in those zones where the electron beam leaks out of small gaps in the beam-confinement electrodes and strike the glass envelope. not all tubes do this- it depends on the impurities in the glass.

Comment: I used a power pentode to produce x-rays, but I had all the glass covered with lead except for the slit aperture.  So maybe I just didn't see it.  Vacuum tubes are really cool little particle accelerators.  Thanks @nielsnielsen

Answer (score 0):

Back in the 60's , GE color TV / CRT put out X-ray because of excessive voltage . Other than that I doubt a CRT generates X-ray. GE discontinued production and totally redesigned their color TV. I bought the new type TV in about 1970 and checked it all over with a Geiger counter ( or scintillation counter , whatever the physicists told me to use) and found no radiation /X-rays.